# Change GraphQl Query POST request to GET

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using
https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-client
library for graphQl but I am facing a issue that is the when I use query it should be a GET request but instead it is showing in the network tab that it is a POST request.

Is there is some extra param that I need to pass in the below code to make it a GET request.[image]

```
  const dataPage = await apolloClient.query({
    query: getCategoryDetail(
      id,
      queryParams,
      enabledFilters,
      region !== undefined ? region : regionID
    ),
    variables: params
  });
```

Below is the query for the product  searching which is working totally fine

```
 let graphql = `
        query category(
            ${params}
        ) { 
            ${defaultCategory != null ? categorySearch : ''}
            products(
                pageSize: $pageSize
                currentPage: $currentPage
                ${textSearch}
                filter: {
                    ${filter}
                }
                sort: {
                    ${sort}
                }
                region:
                  "${region}"
                
            ) {
                ${searchFilters}

                items {
                  ${productFields}
                }

                page_info {
                    total_pages
                    current_page
                }
                total_count
            }
        }
    `;
```

Comment: it should be POST (many reasons: size, encoding) ... 'working' code example is abusing graphql, shouldn't be a string manipulation/template literal but args passed as variables ... as in query on image

Answer (score 0):

GrpahQL operation are always POST request, it should not be GET. Any specific reason why do you want to have a GET request.

Comment: for Caching purpose on the backend side

Comment: I doubt you can use a GET instead of POST request, its how it is .

Answer (score 0):

By default, Apollo Client make POST request.

If you need to use `GET` request then you can use `useGETForQueries`. **Note:** This will make all graphQL calls to GET request. Here's a code sample,

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: from([
    new HttpLink({
      uri: "/graphql",
      useGETForQueries: true, // <--- to enable GET requests
    }),
  ]),
});
```

In case, if you need specific query to use `GET` then use `useQuery` hooks like this,

```js
// useQuery
const { data } = useQuery(query, {
  context: { fetchOptions: { method: "GET" } },
});

// useLazyQuery
const [getEmpData, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(query, {
  context: { fetchOptions: { method: "GET" } },
});
```